Why do electrons not pass through a screen?
Rutherford aimed alpha particles (helium nuclei) at a gold foil and found that most of them went right through and only a few bounced back. If we aim deuterium nuclei (deuterons) at a gold foil we would find even fewer of them bouncing back. And if we aim hydrogen nuclei at a a gold foil even fewer would bounce back.
An electron is about 7,300 times smaller than an alpha particle. So, logically, if we aim electrons at a screen we should find almost all of them sailing right through. Instead, we find that if electrons are passed through a double-slit they form a pattern of bright and dark stripes. And if the double-slit is dispensed with we get a uniformly bright pattern.
Why is this? Why don't electrons go right through the screen?

Maybe because the gold nuclei have electrons around them, which present a serious obstacle to other electrons due to them having the same charge (all other particles you mention are positively charged) and the same mass?

Try some estimates based on momentum.


"If we aim deuterium nuclei (deuterons) at a gold foil we would find even fewer of them bouncing back." Source? This depends on energy of the particle.


I think we need to analyse it in separate parts.

Why electrons don't scatter like alpha particles do?

Electrons have negative charge and alpha particles have positive charge, this fact changes the interaction with the nucleous of the gold atom, which will be attractive with the electron beam. This fact does not change the differential cross section, being equal for the electron and the positron:
$$
{d \sigma\over d\Omega} = {q_1^2q_2^2\over 16E^2} {1\over \sin^4(\theta)}
$$
An electron (or a positron) could scatter in many different ways; it can scatter like a classical particle, described by Newtonian mechanics, but also it can suffer Quantum scattering, as described by Schrodinger or Dirac equations. Usually, what is important to decide how it scatter is its energy, which is usually related to its de Broglie wavelength.
In the experiment of G.P.Thomson and A.Reid, they considered a potential difference between 3.900 V to 16.500 V and they estimated a wavelength for the electrons to the order of $10^{-11}$ m through de Broglie relations. In the experiment of Davisson and Germer, they considered potential differences below 370 V, for which the associated wavelength is to the order of $0.1$ nm (Angstroms).
Since the radius of gold atom is $~ 0.145$ nm, the electrons in the Thompson and Reid experiment would not have shown diffraction in the gold foil, since its wavelength was too small, but the electrons in the Davisson and Germer would. It doesn't mean, however, that they would scatter or not like the alpha particles.
Diffraction is a signature of wave behavior, but in quantum mechanics it could be understood as a signature of quantum behavior. What is important is that, if we are in a quantum regime, the scattering should be governed by the QM rules. However, for the Coloumb potential specifically, the differential cross section is the same for the Classical case, as in the Quantum Mechanics case (see the book Quantum Mechanics, by E. Merzbacher, chapter 13 section 8). It means that, in principle, the electrons scatter like the alpha particles do, despite that they also could show diffraction.

Thanks for the answer and the references. I wonder if there is another explanation. Both de Broglie and David Bohm hypothesised a pilot wave moving with the electron. I conjecture that the diffraction and interference we see are due to the pilot wave (actually a photon) while the electron sails through.
